# Trigger a jenkins job with custom workspace and string parameter using curl

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to trigger a Jenkins job using curl and passing custom Workspace and string parameter.

Comment: What do you mean custom Workspace ? (You want dynamic location to set your build ?)

Comment: Yep, dynamic location.